# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

While working on a simple API for a random quote machine app I got an error saying Uncaught (in promise) Type Error:

+Latest Changes in the Code :-

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtpTQ.jpg):[Code Snippet-1]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Js08.jpg):[Code Snippet-2]

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duH5T.jpg):[Code Snippet-3]

+Latest Error:-

[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0OwQ.jpg):[Error with Response Object]

Comment: try with `res.data[0]` instead instead of `res[0]`, as the `data` is the array.

Comment: tried this but still showing the same error

Comment: Can you please share the API response here, that it would be easier to debug the issue.

Comment: Added, the third image is the response object .

Comment: so you need to write that if condition with `res.data[0].content` and `res.data[0].title` and `res.data[0].link`

Comment: Also tried this still getting that same error :- Image attached

Comment: this is a different error now, your `this` is giving `undefined` on line no 26 , accessing `this.state` throws an error now.

Comment: you need to define state in constructor

Comment: @DhruvRaval tried this still not workking :(

Answer (score 1):

`res` is no array, so it fails when you try to access its element with index `0``.

Try dropping `[0]`. Only the `content` property is an array where you would need it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace res[0].content with res.data[0].content. That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check `res` object for its existence. please start your `if` condition with `if(res[0] && ...)`

Answer (score 0):

res is an object so res[0] is undefined as per your data.
Your actual array is res.data[0]

Answer (score 0):

State in react :

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
              ...
            name:'somethig',              
              ...
        }            
    }
componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserDetail();
}
getUserDetail() {
    axios.get(`some_request_url`)
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                id: response.data.data.id,
                first_name: response.data.data.first_name,
                last_name: response.data.data.last_name,
                avatar: response.data.data.avatar
            });
        })
}
```

To display first name :

`{this.state.first_name}`

This is response from request:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "Janet",
        "last_name": "Weaver",
        "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"
    }
}
```

refer this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

Comment: tried this not working getting error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
    at App.js:29

Comment: you are tring to set state based on request response

Comment: Yes I have got a response object from an API that contains a quote and I am setting my state based on that response object.

Comment: Tried this way no improvement !!

Comment: Uncaught {in promise} TypeError:Cannot read property 'state' of undefined